Understanding Negative Active Resistance in Supercapacitors
I'm seeking clarification on a phenomenon I've encountered regarding supercapacitors. Specifically, I would like to understand what is meant by the negative active resistance of a supercapacitor. How does this negative resistance manifest in the behavior of supercapacitors, and what are the underlying principles or mechanisms that lead to this effect?
Additionally, I would greatly appreciate any references to literature or research articles that discuss this phenomenon in detail.
Thank you in advance for your insights!
EDIT The background of the question is as follows:
There is an active circuit called FDNR (Frequency Dependent Negative Resistance) which is a specific application of the well-known Two-Opamp-Impedance Converter circuit (GIC). This active block has an input resistance of the form (1/s²C).
Therefore, this impedance is frequency-dependent (quadratic function) with a constant phase shift of 180deg. Hence, it ca be described as a negative  resistance which depends on the applied frequency.
Unfortunately, the term "super-capacitor" is frequently used for this block, although it does not show the most important property of a capacitor - a frequency-dependent phase shift.
The FDNR-block is used in active filter topologies which are derived from passive R-L-C structures with the aim to avoid inductances. For transferring these passive circuits into active filters the so-called "Bruton-transformation" is applied.
It would be very helpful to explain the method and its restrictions using a typical example.

I've not heard about it. Any citations or data to illustrate what you're looking at?

Question: Are you speaking about elements which result from the "Bruton Transformation"?

I’m voting to close because the question needs more details, but would be happy to re-open if the OP adds some references and background to clarify the question.

I know what the OP is referring to and I could give some background information (in case the thread would be open again). Am I authorized to edit the question?

I know what the OP is talking about.  Can someone please explain to me why it is not allowed to answer the OP's questions?

@LvW You can Edit the question, and check the flag which resolves the original close reason: https://i.sstatic.net/VbI6iith.png

@LvW Thanks for the edit, I was familiar with the Bruton transformation but I didn't initially connect it with the question about supercapacitors. It's too rare on this site for a closed question that needs more clarity to actually be re-opened.

In the following, I`ll try to explain the principle and the application of a "Frequency Dependent Negative Resistor" (sometimes called "Supercapacitor").
There are many different topologies for active fiters. One of these circuit alternatives is based on the principle to actively realize passive RLC-ladder structures.
Let me start with a simple 2nd-order RLC-lowpass (see below). The transfer function is
H(s)=(1/sC)/[R + (1/sC) + sL]
Without disturbing this transfer function we are allowed to multiply both numerator and denominator with the dimensionless term (1/sT). Of course, "s" ist the complex frequency and T is a time constant which can be freely chosen. However, mathematical considerations require that the product sT is not zero. This restriction has one minor consequence (to be discussed later). This mathematical modification is based on the so-called "Bruton-Transformation" (Bruton 1969).
The modified transfer function now is:
H(s)=(1/s²TC)/[(R/sT)+(1/s²TC)+(L/T)]
Next, the terms in the numerator as well as denominator will be interpreted as new impedances:
R/sT=1/s(T/R)=1/sC" with C"=T/R (in As/V)
L/T=R" (in V/A)
1/s²TC=1/s²D" with D"=TC (in As²/V)
As a result, we have three new components R", C" and D" (resp. impedances) which can realize the passive RLC transfer function - with the advantage that the inductance has disappeared. But a new element D" was created having the dimension As²/V. This element requires an active realization using the well-known "Generalized Impedance Converter GIC" (introduced by Antoniou 1969).
The new C"-R"-D" topology is shown below. It should be noted that the time constant T can be freely chosen with the aim to get "convenient" parts values for R" and C". Realization of D" (GIC) is not critical.
Finally, coming back to the original question, we can conclude that we are using a frequency dependent negative resistor for realizing the required element D". Unfortunately, in some contributions this part D" is called "supercapacitor" (see the newly introduced and commonly agreed symbol), which is - in my opinion - somewhat misleading. The part D" was derived from a capacitor and its impedance is frequency-dependent, but without the typical phase shift of a capacitor.
Comment: As we can see from the picture, the capacitor C" will disturb the desired lowpass charcteristic (see the above mentioned mathematical restriction). Therefore, a suitable additional resistor Rp must be used in parallel to C" (rule of thumb: Rp>>R" and Rp>>1/wpC" with wp=pole frequency)


Thank you!........................

It should be mentioned that the above mentioned method is used for grounded capacitors only - with the aim not to use inductors. For grounded inductors (and floating capacitors) the inductor can be actively realized using the GIC.
